# TypeScript cannot find name 'describe'

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to run angular application. I have wiped `node_module`, reinstall it, install latest typescript version but still I have this error: `Cannot find name 'describe'`, `Cannot find name 'beforeEach'` and others are same.

Here is code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { iocContainer } from '../../utils/ioc';
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';
import { ProductCreationForm } from './ProductCreationForm';
import { ProductStore } from '../../stores/ProductStore';
import * as fileUpload from '../../helpers/fileUpload';
import { FileDialog } from '../ui';

describe('Product creation form', function () {
let store: ProductStore;

beforeEach(() => store = iocContainer.get(ProductStore));
...
```

Maybe problem in package.json or webpack?

Comment: I'm confused, you said angular but within that code, there is nothing angular related. It seems like a unit test for a react component to me.

Comment: add the `specs` under `exclude` of the tsconfig.json as ` "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More like an issue with your typescript definintions and jasmine !

In the `@types/jasmine` package, you have an `index.d.ts` file containing some lines like this

```
declare function describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
```

Could you check if you have them ? Could you also check your `package.json` to see if you all have the dependencies ?

Also, how did you create your project ? was it with the CLI ?

Comment: Actually, there is no @types/jasmine packages. Project was not created with CLI, it was just extracted from the .zip file.

Comment: There is a lot of error in this project, I have asked about one of them. Maybe something wrong in my VS?

Comment: Then you have your issue :) install jasmin and its typings definition with `npm install -D jasmine-core @types/jasmine`